# Exporting individual Congos Reports via command line

Tags: version-control, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm trying to work out how I can export individual Cognos Reports via the command line, for the purposes of source versioning in Git at a report-by-report level. I presume XML would be the output format.

I read that the Cognos SDK can help but you need to build your own solution, which may be possible but this use case feels like something many others would already want and there'd be tooling already.

Of course, importing the individual report would also be needed.

Can anyone help here please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tools like the ones provided by companies like http://www.motio.com. With the free version you can export the XML of the reports but only one by one.

You can also use a Cognos deployment of the reports that generates a zip file with the XML of the reports, but all the reports are in the same file and you will have to extract the XML of the individual reports by hand.

Comment: I'll take a look at motio. We're aware we can export them all in bulk but the go forward idea would be as developers introduce or modify a report, then extract just that report and version control it.

Comment: You must have only a few developers.  That process sounds manual and prone to error or omission.  If you are going down that path anyway, you should have the report developers maintain their own content in git.  If you have a few hundred report developers (like I do), automating the process becomes a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If your end game is version control (Who changed what, when?), you should look into MotioCI.  Last time I looked, there was no free version of MotioCI.

Answer (score 0):

I found the SDK to be cumbersome and, when I got it working, slow.

Yes, report specs are XML.

I have created a process that produces output like what you are asking for.  Here's what it involves:

- A recursive common table expression (CTE) query to get the report
  specs along with the folder structure as seen in Cognos.
- A PowerShell script to run the query and write the results to the file system.
- Another PowerShell script to pull the current content from the remote git repo, run the first PowerShell script, then add, commit, and push the results up to the remote git repo.

I also wrote a PowerShell script to perform the operations associated with git push.  This involves using a program I found called HTML Tidy (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) that can be used to make the XML human-readable.  This helps with diffs in git.  I use TFS, so I get a nice, side-by-side diff if I have tidied the XML.  (Otherwise, it tells me the only line of XML has changed.)

I recently added output for dashboards (exploration) and data sets (dataSet2).  Dashboards are stored as JSON, so my routine had to tidy that (simple in PowerShell).

I run my routine daily, getting new and modified content from the last 3 days (just in case), and weekly to do an entire dump (to capture the deletes).  The weekly process takes about six minutes.  The daily process is negligible.

Before you ask:  I hesitate to provide actual code because I can't take any responsibility for your system.

*Updates:*

Hacking away at the Content Store database is not recommended and it is not supported by IBM.

For reference/comparison:  I'm running IBM Cognos 11.0.7 on IIS on Windows 2012 R2 with the Content Store database on MS SQL Server 2016.  Your system may be different.

**Additional Resources**
https://www.cognoise.com/index.php/topic,28289.msg113869.html#msg113869
https://www.cognoise.com/index.php/topic,17411.msg50409.html#msg50409
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-6
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-2017
https://git-scm.com/docs
http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks and it’s good to see you’ve been able to build something, but without the code, it’s pretty useless.

Comment: Then use MotioPI, MotioCI, or MetaManager.  That's usually the question, right?  Do I have a day to develop this solution, or should I throw money at it?